# Experiment: More aggressive review queue indicator

Tags: discussion

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, I announced [an experiment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445/1438) that would:

- Turn on the review queue indicator whenever there's a task available in any queue.
- All queues with at least one task will be marked with a red dot. There are no grey dots:

  [image: Inbox Zero indicator]

**This *will* mean you'll be notified of outstanding tasks you can't clear.** We are aware of a problem that people will be notified of queues that they don't have the privilege to access. That's next on the list to fix. The goal is to be more aggressive with the indicator to see if we can clear tasks more quickly. Please let us know if we've gone too far.

And in general, we're interested in any feedback to this change: positive, negative or noncommittal.

Comment: Thanks for adding us into the experiment, Jon!

Comment: At the moment of typing this, there are two queues with outstanding tasks, marked correctly with a red dot. However, the review icon indicator is still not turned on for me. Is this a bug?

Comment: @TuringTux: Maybe. There's a one-hour grace period for showing the indicator after you've clicked on it. But there seems to be [a bug as well](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7631/review-queue-indicator-doesnt-show-up-despite-apparently-being-aggressive-now).

Comment: @JonEricson Okay, I see. I tried it again just now (I haven't visited a Stack Exchange site in the previous 12 hours, there is a queue with an outstanding tasks, but I don't see the review icon indicator). I think this means I can confirm the bug.